# c# - how to remove the interval between two timer ticks

Tags: c#, audio, timer, naudio

I am using timer to connect several audio files together. There are a list of audio files and the timer will read files one by one. Once there is an audio read, it will be played. The goal is to play the audio file right after the previous one when it is finished(without any break). 
(I am using Naudio)

Here is the code:

```
 private void timer_key_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if(!isPlaying)
     {
         //play the current audio
         DirectSoundOut dso = sounds2[key_indexer];
         dso.Play();
         targetMusics.Add(dso);
     }
     else
     {
         foreach (DirectSoundOut dso in targetMusics)
         {//stop the current audio
             dso.Stop();
         }
         targetMusics.Clear();
         key_indexer++;     //switch to the next audio
         if (key_indexer >= myMT.Keys.Count)
         {
             key_indexer = 0;
             timer_key.Stop();
         }
     }
     isPlaying = !isPlaying;
 }
```

However, the fact is, when the first music finished, the second one didn't play at once. It comes after one second break. Is this the problem about timer itself? How should I change it?

Comment: The usefulness of the isPlaying variable is very murky.  You simply forgot to call Play() in the else clause.

Comment: @HansPassant I probably get what you mean. Let me try it. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help from @HansPassant. I made a mistake about logic in this timer. Here is the correct code after I applied his suggestion:

```
//stop the current playing
foreach(DirectSoundOut d in targetMusics)
{
    d.Stop();
}
targetMusics.Clear();

//stop the entire process
if (key_indexer >= myMT.Keys.Count)
{
    key_indexer = 0;
    timer_key.Stop();
}
else
{   //play the current audio
    DirectSoundOut dso = sounds2[key_indexer];
    targetMusics.Add(dso);
    dso.Play();

    key_indexer++;
}
```